# How to decode a JSON value that can be a String or null?

Tags: json, deserialization, rust

I am trying to decode JSON in Rust.

JSON examples:

```
[{"id": 1234, "rank": 44, "author": null}]
[{"id": 1234, "rank": 44, "author": "Some text"}]
```

If I use `String` for the author field:

```
#[derive(Show, RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
pub struct TestStruct {
    pub id: u64,
    pub rank: i64,
    pub author: String,
}
```

It throws the error:

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ExpectedError("String", "null")', /home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-dist-rustc-linux/build/src/libcore/result.rs:742
```

How can I decode (filter/ignore null) this JSON value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the type of `author` from `String` to `Option<String>`.

```
#[derive(Show, RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
pub struct TestStruct {
    pub id: u64,
    pub rank: i64,
    pub author: Option<String>,
}
```

Results:

```
Ok([TestStruct { id: 1234u64, rank: 44i64, author: None }]
Ok([TestStruct { id: 1234u64, rank: 44i64, author: "Some text" }])
```